# jQuery Tablet Basic Functions

Tags: jquery, tablet

This is not a question asking how to replicate mouse action on a tablet,
I am aware that there are libraries to take care of mobile devices but my question is simply why will regular jquery it is not running on my tablet.

For example:  I have a datepicker and a carousel, neither of them is working correctly on my tablet.

I understand that mouse action will not work, but surely these simple elements should?

- I am using jquery-1.11.0.min.js
- I have a datepicker on my page
- I am testing on Samsung Tab and also IPad.

The DIV which contains the calendar for the date picker is empty and collapsed. I also have some ajax calls when some buttons are clicked which don't work. These possibly need the jquery library but the calendar should still load and display.

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in a fiddle?

Comment: We need more info than this.  What tablet?  What browser?  What version of jQuery?  Are you using jQuery and/or jQuery mobile?  How are they not "working correctly"?  What do they do?  What do they not do?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What exactly is not working

Comment: I am using jquery-1.11.0.min.js, I have a datepicker on my page, I am testing on Samsung Tab and also IPad.The DIV which contains the calendar for the date picker is empty and collapsed. I also have some ajax calls when some buttons are clicked which don't work. These possibly need the jquery library but the calendar should still load and display

Comment: Alan, add the comment content to your question

Comment: Are you including jQuery UI?  Does your page work on a browser on a "regular" computer?

Comment: Yes I am using jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js. On a desktop all works fine

Answer (score 0):

After pulling out my files one by one and testing I found the culprit. I had an extra exclamatino mark in one of my jQuery files:

```
if(!!('ontouchstart' in window)){
```

This caused my datepicker to be hidden on a tablet (Android) although desktop devices were not affected.

I guess this is because Android has stricter rules when it comes to parsing javascript?